# Problem in installing mathtools.sty

Tags: miktex, installing, mathtools

After performing above procedure

> Permission denied:
>   C:\Users\Sheetal\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\df2c24cb21984fa85003c1ecc818ff83.fndb

is the error

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why don't you install `as administrator`?

Comment: Make sure that you don't have miktex related applications open (e.g. YAP) which block the fndb.

Answer (score 1):

I received a similar error because I had Texworks open at the same time. Also see the answers to this question: [Error in Updating FNDB after last update](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263851/error-in-updating-fndb-after-last-update)