# Error in Updating FNDB after last update

Tags: miktex, updating

After updating packages this morning nothing works anymore (I am working under Windows 8). Particularly, compiling files with TeXWorks returns the message:

running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
The operation failed for some reason.

This is of little help, unfortunately. I tried updating FNDB manually with no change.

Comment: We need a bit more information. For example which latex installation do you use?

Comment: I use PDFLaTeX. The full erroe message in the consol is:                 "You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page (http://miktex.org), if you
need help.

Sorry, but C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\miktex-pdftex.exe did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/cassese/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-pdftex.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page (http://miktex.org), if you
need help."

Comment: And what does the log that is referred to say?

Comment: The log file reports: "2015-09-02 09:58:26,225+0200 FATAL texify - Info: C:\Programmi\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\initexmf.exe
2015-09-02 09:58:26,225+0200 FATAL texify - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process.cpp
2015-09-02 09:58:26,225+0200 FATAL texify - Line: 290". Let me add that i encounter the same problem with all Latex installation, not just Pdflatex. Moreover, after the last update I have the same difficulty on all the devices I use, PC (Windows XP), Laptop (Windows 7) and Tablet (Windows 8). I also tried different editors than Texworks such as Texstudio but it does not work!!

Comment: Instead of using texify do you mind running, say, pdflatex manually. The log you report here does not tell us anything.

Comment: I have just run Pdflatex from the cmd prompt and I get exactly the error message "Miktex configuration utility did not succeed". The log file message is unchanged.

Comment: I'll summon someone who knows more about MikTeX (I haven't used it for years). I've also added the `miktex` tag, as this is highly MikTeX related.

Comment: In another log file I get the following message: "2015-09-02 0:24:56,830+0200 FATAL initexmf - Invalid argument: C:\Documents and Settings\cassese\Impostazioni locali\Dati applicazioni\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\df2c24cb21984fa85003c1ecc818ff83.fndb2015-09-02 10:24:56,830+0200 FATAL initexmf - Info: C:\Documents and Settings\cassese\Impostazioni locali\Dati Applicazioni\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\df2c24cb21984fa85003c1ecc818ff83.fndb2015-09-02 10:24:56,830+0200 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\winFile.cpp
2015-09-02 10:24:56,830+0200 FATAL initexmf - Line: 704". Does this help?

Comment: You'll need to wait until a MikTeX knowledgeable person comes along. It seems to be yet another of those MikTeX update vs MikTeX admin update issues. I tend to use TeXLive (also under windows), and we rarely see those problems. Have you searched the site for similar MikTeX related questions?

Comment: Start the package manager (admin and then user version). Click on "repositories -> synchronize". Then search for new packages starting with miktex and install them. Then try again to create the fndb and the formats.

Comment: I cannot synchronize nor refresh fndb when accessing as user and not as admin

Comment: Did you do the update first as Ulrike asked?

Comment: I cannot do anything as user: update, refresh, package installation.

Comment: OK, I did refresh formats (as admin) and it seems that everything works correctly now. I am relieved, thank you so much!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was resolved in comments ages ago.

Answer (score 4):

Deleting the temporary .fndb files C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\data\le worked for me.