# "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed

Tags: miktex, texify

I have recently installed MiKTeX on my system. It worked well but after I updated it, it does not work and give this messages:

```
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page (http://miktex.org), if you
need help.

Sorry, but D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\texify.exe did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/texify.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page (http://miktex.org), if you
need help.
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled it, but the problem remains. This message is exactly as in 
[MiKTeX won't typeset](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264374/miktex-wont-typeset)
but the solution by Ulrike Fischer does not work.

Update was successful, it was finished, and then I rebooted the computer. The log file is:

```
2015-09-07 08:46:14,122+0330 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
2015-09-07 08:46:14,140+0330 FATAL initexmf - Windows API error 32: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

2015-09-07 08:46:14,140+0330 FATAL initexmf - Info: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\8e909e4b420fa6569f3c98828f47fa74.fndb
2015-09-07 08:46:14,140+0330 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\winFile.cpp
2015-09-07 08:46:14,140+0330 FATAL initexmf - Line: 520
```

Even when I run with pdflatex, but the same error occurs.

```
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page (http://miktex.org), if you
need help.

Sorry, but D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-pdftex.exe did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-pdftex.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page (http://miktex.org), if you
need help.
 and the log file is:
2015-09-07 08:48:29,179+0330 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
2015-09-07 08:48:29,197+0330 FATAL initexmf - Windows API error 32: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

2015-09-07 08:48:29,197+0330 FATAL initexmf - Info: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\8e909e4b420fa6569f3c98828f47fa74.fndb
2015-09-07 08:48:29,197+0330 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\winFile.cpp
2015-09-07 08:48:29,197+0330 FATAL initexmf - Line: 520
```

Comment: And what do all the hopefully helpful log-files contain? Btw: In the comment in the question you linked to I advised not to do first tests with texify.

Comment: Did you use texworks?

Comment: Long time user of miktex (and TeXworks) here. But since it worked fine I never bothered to change anything. Now I needed to install it on another computer, and get the exact same error as posted by Heiko above. Tried synchronizing and updating, running as admin. Nothing worked. Have not tried not using texify, but I'll read up on it.

Comment: This is probably related to a current bug in MikTeX http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2394/. TeXworks block some files needed for MikTeX configuration programmes. If you close TeXworks and compile from the command line everything should work. (If it does not work at first, it might help to delete the `.fndb` files in `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le` )

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/266215/35864, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/265674/35864, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263851/35864