# Run MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 8

Tags: miktex, windows, texworks

I have tried to install MiKTeX 2.9 on my Windows 8 laptop and the installation wizard was running fine and i had no problems. when I was compiling TeX the first time the following occurred:

```
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/Julian/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page (http://miktex.org), if you
need help.

Sorry, but C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\texify.exe did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/Julian/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/texify.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page (http://miktex.org), if you
need help.
```

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Did you use texworks?

Comment: Yes I did use TeXworks

Comment: ...and was trying to complie with XeLaTex

Comment: Try some other editor or the command line. There is currently a bug and texworks interferes with some maintenance tasks miktex wants to do. https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2394/

Comment: thx for your answer. I've followed the link and had run the admin, but I dont know what youe mean by "some other editor or command line".  and how do I check wheter all miktext packs are installed? thank you

Comment: texworks is the editor: Where you type your text. Currently there is a problem with texworks. You can use others, like e.g. texstudio or winedt. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides. To compile on the command line: Rightclick in the windows explorer on the folder of your document and hold down the shift key, in the context menu "choose open command line here", there type `pdflatex name-of-your-tex-file` and hit enter.

Comment: Wonderful! just using the new editor worked out great, thx a lot

Comment: I have voted to close as a duplicate of [MiKTeX: Two things did not succeed](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/265674/35864) since both questions are about bug #2394 in MikTeX. But the other question already has an answer.